# Setting a Backup Policy on Hyper-V 2019 server

Tags: backup, azure, hyper-v, windows-server-2019, windows-server-core

I'm trying to manage the Azure backup for Windows Server 2019 with the Hyper-V feature using Windows Admin Center.  The Server itself is a core server (no GUI).

I cannot find a way to define the "Backup Policy" for my backup, as there is no GUI.

The only message I have is:

```
To modify the backup and retention schedule, open the Microsoft Azure Backup 
application on this server and click on 'Schedule Backup' in the Actions pane 
to modify the backup policy
```

How can I define a backup policy on Windows Server Core (Hyper-V in this case)?

Comment: Are you using a Recovery Services Vault to backup the server?

Comment: It seems so, it is the the backgroud but my interface is Windows Admin Center using web browser.